# Force to unindent default code

Tags: listings, verbatim, code, fancyvrb

I want to unindent the default indent by mmacells. Here you can see the input and output are indented, and i want to force them to the left start. How to do that? Using `\noindent` and `hspace*{-.5cm}` gave me nothing.

[image: indented code]

To make this point clear, i want to remove the blue space before input and the output. And still always be if i add more input and output.

[image]

And here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mmacells,lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1][2]
\begin{mmaCell}[addtoindex=-5,morefunctionlocal={R},morelst={breaklines=true}]{Input}
\{Limit[E^(-\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\sigma}\)}*t)/(R+\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\sigma}\)}),R \(\pmb{\to}\) \mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)}], Limit[1/R,R \(\pmb{\to}\) \mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)}], D[E^(\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)}*t)/(\mmaUnd{R}-\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)}),\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)}], Limit[(R*t*E^(\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)0}*t) - (\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)0}*t*E^(\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)0}*t) + E^(\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)0}*t)))/(R^2 - 2*R*\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)0} + \mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)0}^2), R \(\pmb{\to}\)\mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)}, Assumptions\(\pmb{\to}\)t>0, Assumptions \(\pmb{\to}\)\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\xi}\)0}>0], Integrate[Limit[E^(\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\xi}\)}*t)/(R-\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\xi}\)}),R \(\pmb{\to}\) \mmaDef{\(\pmb{\infty}\)}],\{\mmaFnc{\(\pmb{\xi}\)},-\mmaUnd{\(\pmb{\sigma}\)},0\}]\}
\end{mmaCell}

\begin{mmaCell}{Output}
\{0,0,\mmaFrac{\mmaSup{e}{t\(\xi\)}}{\mmaSup{(R-\(\xi\))}{2}}+\mmaFrac{\mmaSup{e}{t\(\xi\)} t}{R-\(\xi\)},0,0\} 
\end{mmaCell}
\end{document}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Any pointer to `mmacells.sty`?

Comment: @egreg Thanks for reply. I'm sure you can obtain that sty file from here: https://github.com/jkuczm/mmacells#installation

Comment: What indent are you referring to?

Comment: @egreg the horizontal space before Input and Output. I want them to start on the far left of the margin.

Comment: @egreg please see my edit.

Comment: This would require surgery on `listings`, I'm afraid, because the labels are stored by it in a zero width box.

Comment: @egreg Ok. Still thanks for attempting to help. I really appreciate it.